# UWP: Package is not getting generated with error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I have a about 2 yr old in UWP that we are successfully compile and creating package until Visual Studio 16.9. But yesterday I update my Visual Studio to 16.10 and now whenever I try to create a package I got following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070716): The
> specified resource name cannot be found in the image file. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x80070716)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Deployment.AppxFactory.CreatePackageReader(IStream
> inputStream)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Deployment.AppxInteropHelpers.GetAppxManifestReader3(String
> appxFilePath)    at
> Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.AppxPackageFile.ReadAppxPackageFile()
> at
> Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.GenerateAppInstallerFile.AddPackageDependencies(XElement
> dependenciesRoot)    at
> Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.GenerateAppInstallerFile.AddDependenciesIfNecessary(XElement
> element)    at
> Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.GenerateAppInstallerFile.CreateAppInstallerFile(String
> uri, Boolean addOnLaunchUpdateCheck)    at
> Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.GenerateAppInstallerFile.ExecuteImplementation()  Package C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets  6362

I initially thought that installation of VS is corrupted, so I try to reinstall but it was not the case. My application is working fine in debugger mode. But when I try to create package it fails. I can however able to create package if I change my Windows SDK Target to latest `2004`  but then when I run the application from Installed version on test machine it crash after `Splash Screen` i.e. my AppShell do not load.

When searching that error in google it shows that some windows back service has this issue. No reference is found for UWP Package in this regard. I am not sure if some `image file` is missing from package or application or if some system "Image" is missing as in packaging of application.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

EDIT: After I run DSIM to restore windows image it create it once, but only once.

EDIT 2: I found an old machine with Visual studio 16.7.4 and it compile same exact code without any modification just fine. So either the Visual studio update or Windows update (it happens to be my machine get updated to 21h1 today only) with and I didn't realise as I have automatic update enable.

Comment: I made a simple test. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise 16.10. I packaged a UWP app with the Packaging project.  But the result shows that my app is packaged successfully.  Based on your description, the code works correctly on the previous version of Visual Studio without changing anything, it looks like the issue is more related to the Visual Studio.  I'd suggest you submit feedback from Visual Studio to report this behavior. Click on the **Help** Button on the top bar, select **Send Feedback -> Report a Problem**. Then please describe your issue about the VS team will check it.

Comment: I already submit the feedback, but that won't get getting me helped soon, as in any process Microsoft take time to respond and then fix. but I have deliver helpline, plus It see it might be change because of upgrade as in sense that compile is different in this version. So If I can understand those I might be able to compile like older version and get it fixed.

Comment: My suggestion is that just use the old version of Visual Studio instead.

Comment: Can you give me url of offline isntallaer for 16.9 ? I am not finding it anywhere all I am getting is web installer and it do 16.10 only

Comment: I can't help with this because I'm not a Visual Studio expert. You need to ask this in the Visual Studio community. Currently, using the old machine might be better.

Comment: Well the update of visual studio lead to crash of my machine. I have to clean format and install everything. The Error still persist after installation but the twist is that before I had separate package project include that is still keeping crash, but package manifest within UWP app works, so I am using that and remove external project for package.